# text not staying on single line

Tags: html, css

I have text links rotated so they read vertically on the left/right of the page. However, they go on two lines when not given a set width. The text is generated by the title of the links (Wordpress) not hard-coded

css

```
[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous, 
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next { 
position:fixed;
z-index: 999;
top: 50%; bottom: 0;
transform: translateY(-25%);
text-align: center;
}

[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous { left: 0px; }
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next { right: 0px;}

[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous a,
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next a {
position: absolute;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 22px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a visual example of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Vertical *anything*, to me, sounds like it would span across more than 2 lines. As @Aiden said, you'd be best to offer some visuals here (fiddle?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `white-space: nowrap;` to this block to prevent breaking the line.

```
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next a {
position: absolute;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 22px 10px 0 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure it is. You can check it here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp